# Laravel and Phpstorm: model methods not recogniced in collections

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

When I do something like:
        $solicitud = Solicitud::find($id);
        $extras = $solicitud->extras();

PHPstorm doesn't recognize $solicitud as a Solicitud model, and shows a warning in the extras() method:  "method extras is not found in Illuminate/Support/Collection|static"

If I use a @var annotation the warning goes away, but there is a form of fixing this automagically?

Comment: Same problem :). Where do you had the @var annotation ? (this solution is acceptable for me)

Comment: Anywhere before the first appearance of the variable, like this:

/**
* @var Solicitud $solicitud
*/

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem previously with Laravel 4 when models used to just extend `\Eloquent`, whilst that is programatically fine, PHPStorm doesn't know what `\Eloquent` is as its only setup after laravel has run its bootstraping to register the aliases in your config files.

In you model you just need to make it extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Solicitud extends Eloquent {
    // Usual model code
}
```

Comment: I think the question is not about Eloquent method completion (it works with your answer) but custom Solicitud method completion after a `find`(like `comments()`,  or `extras()`). Anyway, maybe I misunderstood your answer or the question :/

Comment: You're right, rap-2-h. The method completion doesn't work with object Collections.